# Graph problem: choose at most n-k vertices, such that if someone else chooses k vertices with the highest value, none of them will be adjacent

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I'm going through previous programming competition problems and I'm not sure how to solve this problem (I've written it out of the original word-problem context).

Given an undirected graph with n nodes, numbered from 1-n and m edges, choose at most n-k nodes, such that if someone else chooses k nodes with the highest numbers (of those you didn't chose), none of your chosen nodes will be adjacent to his (share an edge). Chose as many as possible.

The only solution I can think of is checking all possibilities, but that's way out of the time limit. Is there a way to manipulate the adjacency matrix of the graph to get the solution? Or maybe dynamic programming somehow?

Comment: I don't understand the "choose at most n-k nodes" portion of the problem. Why would you ever choose more than one node?

Comment: Choose nodes that have no edges?!

Comment: Why not choose 0 nodes? Then whatever the other guy chooses, none of his vertices are adjacent to any of yours.

Comment: @orlp I agree that the question is unclear. It seems to lack a goal for the person making the initial choices. [But here's an example where you'd have to choose more than one node.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqMul.png) I assuming that you have to choose at least one node, and n=6, and k=3. The only options are to choose [6,4,2] or [5,3] or [5,3,1].

Comment: @user3386109 That is actually a good point. Although the strategy of choosing 0 nodes always works.

Comment: Sorry for the formulation, you have to choose between 1 and n-k nodes, so 0 is not an option and all nodes have an edge. Yes, in many cases it is easiest to choose one node, but in some, this doesn't give a correct answer. Link to original problem https://pokval21.kattis.com/problems/pokval21.bikupor

Comment: There's an editorial available: https://github.com/Kodsport/swedish-olympiad-2021-public/blob/038520cfc38cdc8cd8c513a077e7d664019900ac/writeups/src/bikupor.md

Answer (score 0):

I assume that an unsaid objective is to choose as many nodes as possible.  Otherwise, as the comments point out, there are several foolish but correct answers.

Here is the pseudo code for selecting as many nodes as possible that meet the requirements.

```
ADD n-k nodes with lowest numbers to a list L
LOOP A over k nodes with highest numbers
    LOOP B over nodes in L
        IF A is adjacent to B
             REMOVE B from L
Output remaining nodes in L
```